# Distribution of matter in the Universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, education, cosmological-inflation, observable-universe

My teacher explained today that quantum fluctuations in the early Universe (in particular, during inflation) determined the spatial distribution of small mass inhomogeneities, which, in turn, due to gravitational attraction, determined the distribution in space of the first celestial bodies (stars and galaxies) and their masses. That is, it was a completely random process.

He also gave an example. If we imagine that the entire universe is much larger than the observable part and conditionally divide it into many regions, each the size of the observable universe, then the distribution of matter in each such region will differ from the distribution of matter in other regions. Is it correct?

Comment: Locally. Otherwise not. See cosmological principle. Basically it depends on what "differ" means.

Comment: @Alchimista It is clear that on a very large scale (on the order of a gigaparsec) all regions are approximately the same. But in detail they will differ. In other regions, there will be other galaxies, other stars, and other planets.